# Least load scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, multitasking, worker

I'm working on a system that uses several hundreds of workers in parallel (physical devices evaluating small tasks). Some workers are faster than others so I was wondering what the easiest way to load balance tasks on them without a priori knowledge of their speed.

I was thinking about keeping track of the number of tasks a worker is currently working on with a simple counter and then sorting the list to get the worker with the lowest active task count. This way slow workers would get some tasks but not slow down the whole system. The reason I'm asking is that the current round-robin method is causing hold up with some really slow workers (100 times slower than others) that keep accumulating tasks and blocking new tasks.

It should be a simple matter of sorting the list according to the current number of active tasks, but since I would be sorting the list several times a second (average work time per task is below 25ms) I fear that this might be a major bottleneck. So is there a simple version of getting the worker with the lowest task count without having to sort over and over again.

**EDIT**: The tasks are pushed to the workers via an open TCP connection. Since the dependencies between the tasks are rather complex (exclusive resource usage) let's say that all tasks are assigned to start with. As soon as a task returns from the worker all tasks that are no longer blocked are queued, and a new task is pushed to the worker. The work queue will never be empty.

Answer (score 1):

How about this system:

- Worker reaches the end of its task queue
- Worker requests more tasks from load balancer
- Load balancer assigns N tasks (where N is probably more than 1, perhaps 20 - 50 if these tasks are very small).

In this system, since you are assigning new tasks when the workers are actually done, you don't have to guess at how long the remaining tasks will take.

Comment: Should have specified, the system pushes tasks to worker. Also batching is not optimal since each batch waits for the longest task to return before new tasks are issued.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to provide more information about the system:

How do you get a task to a worker? Does the worker request it or does it get pushed?
How do you know if a worker is out of work, or even how much work is it doing?
How are the physical devices modeled?

What you want to do is avoid tracking anything and find a more passive way to distribute the work.